# browserify and document ready?

Tags: javascript, browserify, document-ready, onreadystatechange

I'm struggling with using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) events.  How do I craft a module that exports content only available after the document ready event has fired?  How do I depend on such a module?

My first stab was to try to set module.exports asynchronously -- fail out of the box.  My nextx stab at this was for the module to return a function that took in a callback, and called the callback when document ready fired.  Third attempt returned a promise.  This seems to make dependent modules not very modular as now dependent modules and their dependencies (and theirs, turtles all the way down) must also leverage this pattern.

What's a good pattern for using Browserify and document ready events?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
var domready = require("domready");

domready(function () {
    exports.something = /* whatever you want */
});
```

You'll need to download the `domready` package:

```
npm install domready
```

Then just use browserify:

```
browserify input.js -o output.js
```

Yes. It's that simple.

---

Consider that we have two files: `library.js` and `main.js`.

```
// library.js

var domready = require("domready");

domready(function () {
    exports.test = "Hello World!";
});

// main.js

var library = require("./library");
var domready = require("domready");

domready(function () {
    alert(library.test);
});
```

As long as you require your library before you register your main domready function you should be able to use your library seamlessly.

---

Sometimes you may wish to set `module.exports` to a function. In that case you can use the following hack:

```
// library.js

var domready = require("domready");

module.exports = function () {
    return exports._call.apply(this, arguments);
};

domready(function () {
    exports._call = function () {
        alert("Hello World!");
    };
});

// main.js

var library = require("./library");
var domready = require("domready");

domready(function () {
    library();
});
```

Note that the `_call` property is not in any way special.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of listening for a ready event, you can put your browserify bundle in a deferred script tag:

```
<script src="bundle.js" defer></script>
```

This allows you to remove the ready wrapper completely since the bundle will not be executed until the DOM is loaded.

Unfortunately support of `defer` is [patchy](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer), and I don't recommend it unless you don't have to support IE < 10. Consider this answer one for the future, as browser support for it grows.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you have one master file that fires up the entire application, so you can simply wrap it in the ready callback. It doesn't make much sense to do anything before the document is ready anyway. Sure you could return a function in every single file that does DOM manipulation, but that would turn into a mess quickly.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var app = require('./app');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Following this advice would require the user to guarantee that the script has loaded before DOMContentLoaded otherwise the callback will never fire.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in one project, not sure it can work always.

Put the script, for example: `<script src="/path/to/main.js"></script>` right before `</body>`.

In the file going to be `browserify the-file.js -o main.js`.

```
// the-file.js:

var $ = require("jquery");

//......

window.$ = $;  // window is the global object in browsers
$(document).ready(function(){
    // all the old things here ....
});
```

Another way might be better:

```
// the-file.js:

var $ = require("jquery");

//......

(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // all the old things here ....
    });

})($); // Anonymous function get called with $.
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to use `window.onload`
Something along the lines of

```js
const main = () => {

//Your logic here

}

window.onload = main;
```