# Browserify, how to access main.js functions

Tags: javascript, browserify

I can get browserify working but am a little confused about how to access the functions in bundle.js from the DOM.

I have three files-

**message.js**

```
module.exports = function (){
   return "Hello";
};
```

**main.js**

```
var getMessage = require('./message');

//This shows the alert when script loads
alert(getMessage());

//cannot find this function from index.html
function fnClick(){
    alert(getMessage());
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="fnClick();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In the browser when the script loads `alert(getMessage());` in main.js shows the alert but debugger, fnClick is undefined and I can work the scope.

Thanks

Comment: Don't write inline JavaScript. Require your modules in an external file, then Browserify the whole thing, and just include the `bundle.js` file.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but in the example above, that would mean that I have to programmatically add event handler onto the button. Is what you suggest the only way?

Comment: Yes, query the button and add and event listener.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Any code in entry file is executed in the closure. If you look at the created bundle.js, you will see something like this in there.

```
function(require, module, exports) {
    function fnClick() {
        alert(getMessage());
    }
}
```

Anything you create in here will be just hidden to global space unless you explicitly use `window` object (but **don't do that**) to expose it.

---

As @elclanrs said in comments above, just attach the event listener in your main.js code instead of HTML. If you don't want to use external libraries, you can do it hard way.

```
var button = document.getElementById('my-button'); // add id="my-button" into html
button.addEventListener('click', fnClick);
```

Or with library like popular jQuery you would just call.

```
$('#my-button').click(fnClick)
```

Comment: Anyone who gave down vote on this should be ashamed not giving the reason for it.

Comment: This should not be a down vote, it explains the details more relevantly than @idbehold's comments

Comment: Thank you. Side note: in order to get this to work, I had to remove the hash symbol (#) prepended to the "my-button" id when using `document.getElementById`. `document.getElementById('#theButton')` returns `null` while
`document.getElementById('theButton')` returns `<button type=​"button" id=​"theButton">​Click</button>`​.

Comment: Ah, I've missed that. Thanks, it's fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you would like to consider domready package? See [browserify and document ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189910/browserify-and-document-ready) for a great example.

If you are usind domready, your example will become like this:

**message.js** (stays the same)

```
module.exports = function (){
   return "Hello";
};
```

**main.js** (take note of the changes)

```
var domready = require("domready");
var getMessage = require('./message');

domready(function () {

   //This shows the alert when script loads
   alert(getMessage());

   function fnClick(){
    alert(getMessage());
   }     
});
```

**index.html** (stays the same)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="fnClick();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this ? Imo the issue has nothing to do with waiting for DOM to be loaded. Browserify will hide the `fnClick` from global namespace no matter when you actually define it.

Comment: I have tried this way to refactor existing JS functions to Browserify :-)

Answer (score 1):

1) install dom-event-listener as for: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-event-listener

2) in main.js add something like:

```
var domEventListener = require('dom-event-listener');
var element = document.getElementById('my-button');
domEventListener.add(element, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use this over that (current) top answer that recommends adding an event listener to the main.js file?